# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. react native

Tags: react-native

PS D:\MOTOR\kawawamotorsreactapp> npx react-native run-android
warn Package react-native-vector-icons contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed.
Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers
about this.
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
94 actionable tasks: 41 executed, 53 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\BIBEK.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0e660b8bafa777eda46724d78ef391ea\transformed\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\BIBEK.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0e660b8bafa777eda46724d78ef391ea\transformed\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s

```
at makeError (D:\MOTOR\kawawamotorsreactapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\MOTOR\kawawamotorsreactapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\MOTOR\kawawamotorsreactapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\MOTOR\kawawamotorsreactapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: The entire post is the output of console errors. You asked no question or gave any context to your problem. Just posting error output will not get you any responses.